# Having a client sign a contract

Tags: contracts

*This is in regards to me providing a website design/development

I have a potential client which is now simply waiting for me to provide my job proposal.

In terms of the contract side of it, what exactly do I need to supply for something to be considered a 'contract'. The last page of my proposal after the terms of service is simply this type of thing:

Acceptance of Proposal
CLIENT COMPANY NAME (Hidden) authorises My Company Name to perform website development services defined in this proposal at the quoted rates, under the Terms and Conditions detailed above. This page acts as a sales order for the services and products outlined herein and forms a legal contract between the authorised signatory and My Company Name.

SIGNATURE BOX
DATE BOX
PRINTED NAME BOX
COMPANY NAME & POSITION BOX

Is this one little page at the end enough to be a binding contract? If not, what's everyone elses means to this thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: This is not legal advice.

You should also sign on it, and as long as both parties understand what signing on the piece of paper means, it will be enough to be a binding contract. Even verbal agreements can be construed as contract.

When in conflict, normally there is no way to deny unless he wasn't sane when he signed it or he can prove he was misled into signing, or if the terms and conditions "above" are ambiguous and he has [mistaken](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mistake_(contract_law)). As such it will be the terms clauses that are under scrutiny, not the final acceptance clause. You should check what are the ways the contract can be voided and try to cover those grounds.

Answer (score 0):

You must learn the laws governing the business agreements IN THE LOCALE you are in. Because these may change from locale to locale.

For example in Europe, agreeing to something in an email that can be reliably tracked back to you is legally acceptable as evidence.

In some countries, verbal agreement is also acceptable - despite it is extremely unreliable to prove.

In some countries which are decentralized, local laws may override federal laws or there may be federal laws which may override everything. (Like usa, india, spain).

Therefore, it is rather silly to ask this here - you MUST seek a legal counsel in the place you are conducting your business in.